# code-igniter error_404 page design is not showing when using wrong controller name

Tags: php, codeigniter

IN code-igniter error_404 page design is working properly in hmvc when i use a wrong function name but when i am using wrong controller name in hmvc section its showing a blank page.below i mention the both url type in which i get the error_404.php design .
1)error page design is working with this type url

```
http://localhost/projectName/moduleName/ControllerName/wrongFunctionName
```

2)blank page is showing with this type of url

```
http://localhost/projectName/moduleName/incorrectControllerName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

Set an 404 override in config/routes.php:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'utils/page_not_found';
```

Create a module utils and a controller Page_not_found.php that loads your 404 view or layout. It is just an example off course.

In your index use:

```
public function index() {
    $this->output->set_status_header('404'); // setting header to 404
    // ... more code
}
```